# Can a Firefox window be re-opened if another Firefox window was open at closing time?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

It seems this is possible with Chrome by pressing Ctrl + Shift + T and it does work in Firefox as well if only 1 window is open, close it, then it can be re-opened again. But if I have 2 windows open, close one, cannot re-open with said method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> reopens the last "tab" or set of tabs. If you closed a window rather than a tab it will open the last window.

To reopen *windows* there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Alternatively there is the Recently Closed Windows area in the history:

[image]

If you click the <kbd>></kbd> next to `Recently Closed Windows` then you should be able to reopen any recent window you closed.